# changed menu bar colour and now can no longer see menu when hovering over button

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar which contains a button which when is hovered over, displays a list of menu items.

I recently changed the colour of my menu bar from a solid colour to a more modern  colour which has gradients etc.

I also changed my button to be the same colour. However having down that when I hover over the menu nothing is display anymore. I can't understand why having changed the colour would have done this and how to see the menu again?

Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waLpk14a/226/)

**new colour**

```
     /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
   box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
   background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #bddbfa), color-stop(1, #80b5ea));
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background-color:#bddbfa;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
  }
```

**before the change**

```
   /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
   background-color: #9FACEC;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
  }
```

Comment: Post code for :hover pseudo style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this was related to the colour change, just a minor accidental html code tweak while updating probably.
I was slightly confused that there was an outer div that didn't seem to do anything (no associated css classes), and I removed it. After I did this and moved a separate closing `</div>` tag in your html, only a minor update to a css class was necessary to make this work (I moved the dropdown class up in the css and included `position:relative` .. minor things).

Here is working code and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/s7p8emt2/)

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/*padding: 6px 5px;*/

.navbar {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navbar div {
  height: 5px !important;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.two {
  width: 35px;
}

.three {
  width: 50px;
}

.navbar:hover div {
  width: 60px;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #bddbfa), color-stop(1, #80b5ea));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background-color: #bddbfa;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropbtnSub {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content li {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.dropdown-content-list {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content-list:hover {
  display: block !important;
}

.dropdown-content-li:hover .dropdown-content-list {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}


/*background-color: #9FACEC;    /* Medium blue */

#menu {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #bddbfa), color-stop(1, #80b5ea));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
  background-color: #bddbfa;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: Red;
  /* Red */
}


/*height: 500px;*/

.content {
  /*background-color: #F5CF8E;    /* Yellow */
  background-color: yellow;
  /* Yellow */
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 800px;
}

.page {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.headerLbl {
  align-self: center;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="menu">

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="one"></div>
                        <div class="two"></div>
                        <div class="three"></div>
                    </div>
          </button>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown-content-li">
            <button class="dropbtnSub">Region</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content-list">
              <ul>
                <li>Japan</li>
                <li>Europe</li>
                <li>USD</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-content-li">
            <button class="dropbtnSub">Export</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content-list">
              <ul>
                <li>Excel</li>
                <li>CSV</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


    </div>


    <div id="lblContainer" class="headerLbl">
      My label
    </div>


    <div class="page">


    </div>

  </div>



</body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Being tearing my hair out, still in my early days of html & css. I will award the bounty to you however I'm not allowed to yet apparently it is to soon but I will check back tomorrow

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

use :hover and give your color which u can identify on over

```
 .dropdown:hover{
    write your code here;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .dropbtn {
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
   box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
   background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #bddbfa), 
   color-stop(1, #80b5ea));
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #bddbfa 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background-color:#bddbfa;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
  }
  .dropbtn:hover
   {
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
   box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
   background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #9FACEC), 
   color-stop(1, #80b5ea));
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #9FACEC 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9FACEC 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #9FACEC 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #9FACEC 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #9FACEC 5%, #80b5ea 100%);
   background-color: #9FACEC;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
  }



<html>
<body>
<input class="dropbtn" type="button" value="button"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code Works check

Comment: it still doesn't work. Have you tried it in jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/juadw2mk/...its working check it...remove style tag add only properties in css section of jsfiddle and check.

Comment: sorry that link keep saying forbidden